# Send email with attachment dynamically.?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email

I want to attach files dynamically with emails..may be computer you can say..Can we do that...I have created a VF page and using apex:inputfile...Can we send email with attachments..Please provide me some sample code.

```
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
 mail.setToAddresses(emailList);           
 String subject='Trend Analysis Report-PI';
 transient Messaging.EmailFileAttachment [] efaList = new  List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> () ;
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName(filename );
        efa.setBody(fileBody);
        efa.setContentType(conType);
        efaList.add(efa) ;

        if(efaList != null) {
        mail.setFileAttachments(efaList) ;
        }
        mail.setCharset('UTF-8'); //Use Signatue
        mail.setUseSignature(true);
        // Send the email

                    mail.setSubject(subject);


        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

**VF page**

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!filebody}" fileName="{!filename}" contentType="{!conType}">
```

I am also getting view state error while uploading file....Can some one tell me how to dynamically attach files.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use setFileAttachments on the Messaging.SingleEmailMessage object:

```
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment attachment = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
attachment.setBody(fileBody);
attachment.setContentType(conType);
attachment.setFileName(filename);
attachment.setinline(false);
mail.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] { attachment } );
```

Comment: I am getting heap size error while uploading even a smaller file...maximum view state size limit (135kb) exceeded..can you help me solve that..

Comment: You can use Transient keyword for variable that are not required to post.That helps in decreasing view state.

Comment: This works, but has anyone figured out how to get HTML recorded into the task? I even tried putting all the HTML into an attachment, but the email's attachment isn't recorded in activity history.